# Remove duplicate rows on the same timestamp but keep certain rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to remove the exact duplicates on the same timestamp, but on the duplicates with the same timestamp where Status is Offline and Online, keep the ones Online.

Here's how this dataframe was created :

```
hf = sf0.loc[(sf0['provider_id' ] == '0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b') & (sf0['Date'] == '2017-09-04')].sort_values('Time')
```

```
         provider_id                            dt          Status     Date       Time

372 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 08:00:19 Online  2017-09-04  08:00:19
426 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 08:29:39 Offline 2017-09-04  08:29:39
443 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 08:44:36 Offline 2017-09-04  08:44:36
450 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 09:06:12 Online  2017-09-04  09:06:12
404 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 12:23:24 Offline 2017-09-04  12:23:24
402 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 12:23:47 Offline 2017-09-04  12:23:47
354 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 12:45:46 Offline 2017-09-04  12:45:46
538 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 12:45:46 Online  2017-09-04  12:45:46
387 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 12:45:56 Offline 2017-09-04  12:45:56
419 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 17:38:31 Offline 2017-09-04  17:38:31
493 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 17:38:31 Online  2017-09-04  17:38:31
494 0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b    2017-09-04 17:40:51 Online  2017-09-04  17:40:51
```

I tried the following code to remove but the results removed the online values as well. Simple drop_duplicates didn't work either

```
newdf1 = hf.groupby('Time').first().drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sorting `Time` and `Status` columns and remove duplicates by `Time` column with keep last row for keep the Online:

```
df = hf.sort_values(['Time','Status']).drop_duplicates('Time', keep='last')
print (df)
                          provider_id                   dt   Status  \
372  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 08:00:19   Online   
426  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 08:29:39  Offline   
443  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 08:44:36  Offline   
450  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 09:06:12   Online   
404  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 12:23:24  Offline   
402  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 12:23:47  Offline   
538  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 12:45:46   Online   
387  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 12:45:56  Offline   
493  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 17:38:31   Online   
494  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04 17:40:51   Online   

           Date      Time  
372  2017-09-04  08:00:19  
426  2017-09-04  08:29:39  
443  2017-09-04  08:44:36  
450  2017-09-04  09:06:12  
404  2017-09-04  12:23:24  
402  2017-09-04  12:23:47  
538  2017-09-04  12:45:46  
387  2017-09-04  12:45:56  
493  2017-09-04  17:38:31  
494  2017-09-04  17:40:51
```